# TensorFlow Binary Image Classification: Predict Probability of each class for each image in data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, classification

I am building a TensorFlow model for Binary Image Classification. I have two labels "good" and "bad"
I want the model should output for each image in the data set, whether that image is good or bad and with what probability

For example if I submit 1.jpg and let's suppose it is "good" image. Then the model should predict that 1.jpg is good with 100% probability and bad with 0% probaility.

So far I have been able to come up with following

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(input_shape, input_shape, 3)),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
  #
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
  #
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
  ##
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  ##
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  ##
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

The shape of output from the above model is 1 x 1. But I think this will not serve my purpose.

I am compiling the model in this way

```
 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
 model_fit = model.fit(train_dataset,
                  steps_per_epoch=3,
                  epochs=30,
                  validation_data=validation_dataset)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: how are you compiling the model?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is looking for an answer, below is the python code for model generation

Some of the points to be noted here are

1. Input Image shape is 360x360x3
2. Activation Function for last layer is "**softmax**" instead of "**sigmoid**"
3. Loss function is "**sparse_categorical_crossentropy**" instead of "**binary_crossentropy**"
4. **Shape of output is 2 instead of 1**

Please note #2, #3 and #4, even though I am trying to come up with a model for Binary Image Classification. My ultimate aim was to convert this model to TensorFlow Lite version and use TensorFlow Lite model in Android Application.

Earlier, when I was using "sigmoid" for last layer and "binary_crossentropy" as loss function, the output shape of last layer cannot be greater than 1.

As a result when I was using the Lite model generated out of that TensorFlow Model in Android application, I was getting an error which is mentioned below

> "Cannot find an axis to label. A valid axis to label should have size
> larger than 1"

With the changes mentioned in #2, #3, and #4, the Lite Model generated works fine in Android.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop


print("version")
print(tf.__version__)

train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
validation = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

input_shape = 360
train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('container_images/train/',
                                          target_size=(input_shape,input_shape),
                                          batch_size=3,
                                          classes=['good', 'bad'],
                                          class_mode='binary')

validation_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('container_images/validation/',
                                          target_size=(input_shape,input_shape),
                                          batch_size=3,
                                          classes=['good', 'bad'],
                                          class_mode='binary')

print(train_dataset.class_indices)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(input_shape, input_shape, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    #
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    #
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model_fit = model.fit(train_dataset,
                      steps_per_epoch=3,
                      epochs=30,
                      validation_data=validation_dataset)
```

Comment: Can you show us the android code ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to make your model output "Good" and "Bad" as labels, instead, you could output probabilities for each one independently, in other words, the probability of the image being good and the probability of the image being bad. Make the size of the output of your last layer to be 2. So your model will now output a 2-dimensional vector such that [1.0, 0.0] means 100% good and 0% bad and [0.0, 1.0] means 0% good and 100% bad. Use binary cross-entropy as your loss function for training. Of course, you have to label your training data similarly, so if you have a good training example, label it as [1.0, 0.0] since you are 100% sure that it is good and if you have a bad training example label it as [0.0, 1.0] since you are also 100% sure that it is a bad example.

The reason I told you to use binary-cross entropy as a loss function is so that the model will learn to output opposing probabilities for the components of the 2-d vector output. So if it is a good image, the first component will be high and the second component will be low and vice-versa if it is a bad image. Also, after training, when making predictions, you only take the highest probability of the two, if the higher probability is the first one, then it is a "Good" image and you use that probability only.

Comment: I changed the shape of the last layer to 2 tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid') but now I am getting error while running the python program. ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))

Comment: What is the version of tensorflow that you are using? I used version 2.2.0 and your code works after changing the size of the last layer to 2.

Comment: Thank You for the help. I made few more changes to make it work. I changed loss function to "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", activation function for last layer as "softmax" instead of "sigmoid" and also as suggested I changed the size of output in the last function as 2.